# Saving 24bit .ico to a file - Works with Debugger, NOT without

Tags: c#, debugging, dll, imaging, ico

I am experiencing an unknown issue while trying to save a real 24bpp ico to a file.

I am using the IconEx.dll i found here: [Vb icon thingy project](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?396650-Create-Valid-Icon-Files!-In-24-bit-true-color!)

I rewrote the original VB code you can see there into C# (following one).

My problem is strange. When Running Debug/Release version using F5 OR attaching the debugger to the .exe manually (adding a sleep() at the beginning for me to be able to attach the Debugger easily), everything goes OK!

When i just run the .exe (Release or Debug), the empty temporary (black) .ico write successfuly, but the final ico is just corrupted...
Do you see any common problem maybe? i've been trying many things to fix this for now 4 days... even putting sleep() everywhere to slow down the process maybe etc

Both icons (correct one or corrupted one), have the same size at least 9.43Ko

Thank you.

```
//create a temporary icon from a Bmp

            Bitmap nwbmp = new Bitmap(48, 48, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            IntPtr pntr = nwbmp.GetHicon();
            Icon nwico = Icon.FromHandle(pntr);
            DestroyIcon(pntr);
            using (System.IO.Stream st = new System.IO.FileStream(pathToFinaleIco, FileMode.Create)) {
                System.IO.BinaryWriter wr = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(st);
                nwico.Save(st);
                wr.Close();
            }
            nwbmp.Dispose();


            //create the final icon by writing in the temp one and then saving to hdd overwritting to it
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("path.to.file.bmp", new Size(48, 48)); //<== takes the bmp i want the ico to looks like
            IconEx Iconex = new IconEx(pathToFinaleIco);  //<=== load the temp ico file ill overwrite to be final one
            Iconex.Items.RemoveAt(0);
            IconDeviceImage IcondeviceImage = new IconDeviceImage(new Size(48, 48), ColorDepth.Depth32Bit);
            IcondeviceImage.IconImage = new Bitmap(bmp);
            Iconex.Items.Add(IcondeviceImage);
            Iconex.Save(pathToFinaleIco);
            //end
            bmp.Dispose();
```

Comment: Just as an experiment - try running your exe with Administrative Privileges...

Comment: Are you sure IcondeviceImage.IconImage = new Bitmap(bmp); is correct? Should it possibly be pathToFinaleIco and them save to somewhere else as the final icon? If you break the problem in two (creating the bitmap and then creating the icon) it may be easier to debug each piece - even consider refactoring them in to two Methods.

Comment: @developer82 : Running as admin didn't change the problem. Murray :bmp is the correct one since it take the picture i want as icon to "inject it" into the ico. The first part of the script creating an empty ico file is working properly, only the second one fails by corrupting the .ico file.

Comment: Specify a full path to the bmp file, or set the working directory.

Comment: @MarkJansen Its already only using full path. I tried something, added a PictureBox. everytime i try  `pictureBox1.Image = bmp;` it crashes, debugger or not, and can't catch the Exception. If i try `pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(bmp);` it only fails same WITHOUT debugger.

Comment: Answered below with a working sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dedicated my lunch break to this, try the below in a console application, you will need to add appropriate references. Worked great in any mode (debug, release, command prompt etc).

[Source Code here](http://1drv.ms/1U4CTOV)

Program.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BmpMadness
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Image bmp = Image.FromFile("target.bmp"))
            using (Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(bmp, new Size(48, 48)))
            using (Bitmap newFormatBmp = newBmp.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, newBmp.Width, newBmp.Height), PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
            {

                // DestroyIcon(pntr);   - dont need it. 
                using (System.IO.Stream st = new System.IO.FileStream("final.ico", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    IntPtr pntr = newFormatBmp.GetHicon();
                    Icon nwico = Icon.FromHandle(pntr);
                    System.IO.BinaryWriter wr = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(st);
                    nwico.Save(st);
                }

                //create the final icon by writing in the temp one and then saving to hdd overwritting to it
                using (var Iconex = new IconEx("final.ico"))
                {
                    Iconex.Items.RemoveAt(0);
                    IconDeviceImage IcondeviceImage = new IconDeviceImage(new Size(48, 48), ColorDepth.Depth32Bit);
                    IcondeviceImage.IconImage = new Bitmap(bmp);
                    Iconex.Items.Add(IcondeviceImage);
                    Iconex.Save("deviceImage.ico");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! So, `final.ico` is OK, black background though. And `deviceImage.ico` is corrupted... sadly.

Comment: .Net 4.0 on my machine (Windows 7 x64). Sounds like it may be an issue with your machine. What are you using to view the icons? Also, did you use your version of IconEx or the one in my download. And lastly, did you try with my sample source image. Your issue may be in the conversion to the 24 bit bmp rather than the Icon generation. Good luck!

Comment: So, i was able to load your project (im in Visual Studio 2010). My project were using .Net 3.5. and im on Vista. (yea ughh). But your project worked. I mean the Icon isn't corrupted. So i will try anything some things between your project and mine, like changing framework (last thing i will try tho) etc. Thanks again.

Comment: Changing framework to .NET 4.0 fixed it... sadly my main program is on 3.5 for compatibility reasons yet... I will ty to find a workaround... hope i will find one..

Comment: Glad you have found your way to a working version, even if not on your preferred framework version. Keep in mind Vista supports .net framework 4.5 which is a side by side install to 3.5, so you could use an inter-process call to leverage the newer framework, for example, writing the converter as a console application and using Process.Start to call it or even a simple local web service to create the process separation. Good luck!